# How to fix this error when using React Context

Tags: themes, material-ui, react-context

I'm trying to implement React-context in my application to get rid of the props drilling. While creating the contextProvider, I'm getting the following error-
 "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports".

const SharedThemeContext = React.createContext();

```
export class SharedThemeProvider extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      message: '',
    };
  }

  openSnackbar = (message) => {
    this.setState({
      message,
      isOpen: true,
    });
  };

  closeSnackbar = () => {
    this.setState({
      message: '',
      isOpen: false,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <SharedThemeContext.Provider
        value={{
          openSnackbar: this.openSnackbar,
          closeSnackbar: this.closeSnackbar,
          snackbarIsOpen: this.state.isOpen,
          message: this.state.message,
        }}
      >

        {children}
      </SharedThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export const SharedThemeConsumer = SharedThemeContext.Consumer;
```

Comment: Thats what I get each time.....I tried adding    the following bit but still the same error...                                                         static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
  }

Comment: Resolved the error- I had snackbarprovider as snackbar in my app.js

Answer (score 0):

Do the warnings provide any information?